# Naming Tomcat worker threads

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, monitoring

Is there a simple way to change the default name that Tomcat gives its worker threads? Ideally, I'd like all the threads associated with a certain web application to have it in their name, perhaps as a prefix. For example, if I deploy app1.war and app2.war, I'd like all the threads for app1 to have *app1* in their name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [a forum](http://tomcat.10.n6.nabble.com/Change-thread-name-of-HTTP-worker-threads-at-Runtime-td2143050.html), reposted here with a bit better formatting; a simple [filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Introduction), that renames each thread to the request URI, in this example:

```
public class ThreadNameFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter { 

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, 
        FilterChain fc) throws IOException, ServletException { 

        HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest)req; 
        final Thread curThr = Thread.currentThread(); 
        final String oldName = curThr.getName(); 

        // change the name of the current thread to something related
        // to the application (e.g. URI)
        try { 
            curThr.setName(httpReq.getRequestURI()); 
            fc.doFilter(req, resp); 
        } finally { 
            curThr.setName(oldName); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Threads are only temporarily "associated" with a particular webapp.

I can't imagine why this would be something useful at all:

- Logging should include context information (e.g. what component is logging)
- Profiling can easily reveal what code is being executed (and thus reveal the webapp that is "running")
- Exceptions include full stack traces and can reveal what code was being executed (and thus reveal the webapp that was "running")
- Long-running threads can be inspected via a thread-dump (and thus reveal the webapp that is "running" in the long-running request)

Comment: I'm looking at heap dumps on a system with more than one webapp running.

Comment: Heap dumps don't contain any information about threads, other than that the threads are represented by Java objects, so naming the threads (even temporarily) does not add any useful information to a heap dump.